# Javascript conflicts with Bootstrap functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I'm building a site that contains a Bootstrap Nav Tab section. The problem is my dev team is implementing an accessibility javascript that conflicts with Bootstrap. I am attaching a link to a codepen showing the problem. (See Below). Which its basically the nav tabs simply do not work. No click event is happening.

I don't have much experience with accessibility scripting but I am hoping someone here does and can tell me how to make bootstrap work without losing the functionality this accessibility script provides.

The script is designed to allow non-sighted users using screen readers (i.e. JAWS) to be able to tab around the menus and screen items based on what JAWS is telling them by reading the ARIAS and navigating through ROLES.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav').setup_navigation();
});
var keyCodeMap = {
   48:"0", 49:"1", 50:"2", 51:"3", 52:"4", 53:"5", 54:"6", 55:"7", 56:"8", 57:"9", 59:";",
65:"a", 66:"b", 67:"c", 68:"d", 69:"e", 70:"f", 71:"g", 72:"h", 73:"i", 74:"j", 75:"k", 76:"l",
77:"m", 78:"n", 79:"o", 80:"p", 81:"q", 82:"r", 83:"s", 84:"t", 85:"u", 86:"v", 87:"w", 88:"x", 89:"y", 90:"z",
96:"0", 97:"1", 98:"2", 99:"3", 100:"4", 101:"5", 102:"6", 103:"7", 104:"8", 105:"9"
} 


$.fn.setup_navigation = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        menuHoverClass: 'main-menu-item',
    }, settings
);

// Add ARIA role to menubar and menu items
$(this).attr('role', 'menubar').find('li').attr('role', 'menuitem');
var top_level_links = $(this).find('> li > a');

//// Set tabIndex to -1 so that top_level_links can't receive focus until menu is open
//$(top_level_links).next('ul')
//.attr({ 'aria-hidden': 'true', 'role': 'menu' })
//.find('a');    


// Adding aria-haspopup for appropriate items

$(top_level_links).each(function(){
    if($(this).next('ul').length > 0)
        $(this).parent('li').attr('aria-haspopup', 'true');
});
$(top_level_links).each(function(){
    if($(this).next('ul').length > 0)
        $(this).parent('ul').attr('aria-haspopup', 'true');
});


$(top_level_links).hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul')
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
        .find('.'+settings.menuHoverClass)
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'true')
        .removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a')
        //.attr('tabIndex',-1);


$(this).next('ul')
    .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
    .addClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
    .find('a').attr('tabIndex',0);
});


$(top_level_links).focus(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul')
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
        .find('.'+settings.menuHoverClass)
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'true')
        .removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a')
        //.attr('tabIndex',1);
    $(this).next('ul')
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
        .addClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a').attr('tabIndex',0);
});


// Bind arrow keys for navigation
$(top_level_links).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This is the first item
        if($(this).parent('li').prev('li').length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('ul').find('> li').last().find('a').first().focus();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('li').prev('li').find('a').first().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent('li').find('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).parent('li').find('ul')
            .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
            .addClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
            .find('a').attr('tabIndex',0)
            .last().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This is the last item
        if($(this).parent('li').next('li').length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('ul').find('> li').first().find('a').first().focus();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('li').next('li').find('a').first().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent('li').find('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).parent('li').find('ul')
            .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
            .addClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
            .find('a').attr('tabIndex',0)
            .first().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    // If submenu is hidden, open it
    //e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li').find('ul[aria-hidden=true]')
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'false')
        .addClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a').attr('tabIndex',0)
        .first().focus();
    } else if(e.keyCode == 27) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.'+settings.menuHoverClass)
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'true')
        .removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a')
        //.attr('tabIndex',-1);
    } else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('ul[aria-hidden=false] a').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().substring(0,1).toLowerCase() == keyCodeMap[e.keyCode]) {
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
            }
        });
    }
});

var links = $(top_level_links).parent('li').find('ul').find('a');

$(links).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // This is the first item
        if($(this).parent('li').prev('li').length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('ul').parents('li').find('a').first().focus();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('li').prev('li').find('a').first().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).parent('li').next('li').length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('ul').parents('li').find('a').first().focus();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('li').next('li').find('a').first().focus();
        }
    } else if(e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this)
        .parents('ul').first()
        .prev('a').focus()
        .parents('ul').first().find('.'+settings.menuHoverClass)
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'true')
        .removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a')
        //.attr('tabIndex',-1);
    } else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    } else {
        var found = false;
        $(this).parent('li').nextAll('li').find('a').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().substring(0,1).toLowerCase() == keyCodeMap[e.keyCode]) {
                $(this).focus();
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if(!found) {
            $(this).parent('li').prevAll('li').find('a').each(function(){
                if($(this).text().substring(0,1).toLowerCase() == keyCodeMap[e.keyCode]) {
                    $(this).focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});


 //Hide menu if click or focus occurs outside of navigation
$(this).find('a').last().keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 9) {
        // If the user tabs out of the navigation hide all menus
        $('.'+settings.menuHoverClass)
        .attr('aria-hidden', 'true')
        .removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass)
        .find('a')
        //.attr('tabIndex',-1);
    }
});


$(document).click(function () {
    $('.' + settings.menuHoverClass).attr('aria-hidden', 'true').removeClass(settings.menuHoverClass).find('a').attr('tabIndex', 0);
});

$(this).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
}
```

The HTML is in the pen link attached for the sake of not cluttering this question. Besides, you'll be able to test it there better.

[**CODEPEN DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYLjPO)

p.s. Also, I am using a small Bootstrap accordion within one of the Tabs. (Not shown in the demo for simplicity purposes). So if you think of a fix that can globally fix all Bootstrap functionality rather than the navtabs only, I'll appreciate it even more, but I am not expecting it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem? You said there's some kind of conflict but you left out all details.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I edited the question. But the problem is the nav tabs don't work at all. Nothing happens when they are clicked. But if I delete the javascript, everything is golden. See the demo I included. You'll see what I mean. CTRL + X the Javascript and run and you'll see it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this event handler at the very end of the code in the CodePen:

```
$(this).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That's explicitly preventing clicks on the menu tabs from bubbling up to any other event handler. Probably the Bootstrap tab code binds its event handlers at the top of the DOM.

It's not clear what the intention of that code is; it's not commented and it's not apparent from looking at the rest of the code. It may be just a gratuitous addition, in which case it's erroneous given the nature of that code.